# Request.Form[“__EVENTTARGET"] value not clearing

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, postback

When I try to log off the system, my login page is loaded. After that press the browser back button and it shows web page has expired and when I refresh the page, the database call is again made since the value in Request. Form[“__EVENTTARGET”] attribute and textbox values are retaining its previous values and the function for logging in is again executed.

Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Ex : Server side code is given below:

> if (IsPostBack)
>            {
>               string parameter = Request.Form["_*EVENTTARGET"];
>               string argument = Request.Form["*_EVENTARGUMENT"];
>
> ```
>         if (parameter == "LOGIN")
>         {
>             ValidateLoginDetails();
>         }
>      }
> ```

After log off, When I press the browser back button, browser shows web page has expired. Then I refreshed the page and I am getting the values of the string parameter. What can be the reason and how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Post some source code. It's not quite easy to find solution without code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't logged the user out correctly - you shouldn't be able to hit server-side code on a page that's configured to be authenticated until authentication has happened.

Another option is that there's a problem with the authentication configuration - have you checked that User.Identity.Name returns the value you expect?